# Monitor Impala using Ganglia

Tags: hadoop, impala, ganglia

Is it possible to monitor Impala using Ganglia? There is no reference to it on the Impala documentation and all metrics from Hadoop can be monitored from it. Is there a way to connect the performance metrics generated by Impala on Ganglia?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't off-the-shelf available TMBK. However you could try this [Grafana](https://engineering.hellofresh.com/monitoring-and-logging-in-impala-417930ea0aed) solution, and if necessary, intergrate it into Ganglia. It'd also worth mentioning that impala's built-in web page has tons of metrics and a nice dynamic query plan SVG visualizer.

Comment: Thanks. I already have a solution using Ganglia and my goal is to show only one dashboard. Using Grafana then passing to Ganglia is not what I was hoping for. It seems that I'll have to parse the web ui itself anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that will do. Impala uses a forked version of mongoose (due to license issue). The related web code is quite straightforward. Good luck!